# C# CheckBoxList Foreach item not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a checkbox list that isn't updating on the looping through it.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblRoles" runat="server">
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Pretty straight forward, the code behind:

```
List<ListItem> listRoles = AdminRole.GetRolesList(false);


    cblRoles.DataSource = listRoles;
    cblRoles.DataValueField = "Value";
    cblRoles.DataTextField = "Text";
    cblRoles.DataBind();
    foreach (ListItem listItemRoles in cblRoles.Items)
    {
        listItemRoles.Enabled = true;
        listItemRoles.Selected = true;
        listItemRoles.Text = "test";
        listItemRoles.Value = "test";}
```

The data inside the checkbox list isn't updating at all, even though the stepthrough debugger seems to work as expected.  It does bring out the list as expected in the function that calls the data. FYI this is inside the `(!isPostBack)` check so that it isn't rebinding it again.  I am stumped as to why this isn't working.

Comment: what is the point on updating manually with a foreach if your items are coming from the listRoles List and you are in bound to DataSource mode?

Comment: I've edited your question, but please be mindful of potentially offensive language.

Comment: What event is responsible for invoking this code?

Comment: Apart from your issue, why aren't you adding the ListItems manually by adding them in a `foreach` from `listRoles`?

Comment: @James Johnson: I think this was an excellent example why even in test code you don't expect others to see you still use the kind of variable names and strings that you could give to a client. :)

Comment: Apologies for the language.  Urgh found a master control was setting this to autobind.  Pfffft 1 hour lost.  FYI the update was going to grab a list ot all roles and loop through and set the selected on it.   It wouldn't work hence I added text and value to see if that would work.  Thanks for your responses :D

Comment: @jimmy: I would check to see if there's anywhere else the list is databound after that code is executed. That seems like the most likely culprit until you've ruled it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Text & Value I Love! But it seems that you are re-assigning values? you did already bind it.

```
foreach (ListItem listItemRoles in cblRoles.Items)
{
    listItemRoles.Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess if the debugger is telling you it is doing the right thing is that at some point after this the page is having its `DataBind()` method called. This will call DataBind on all children including this control. This will then rebind from the Datasource, losing your changes.

As others have said you probably want to change your list that you are databinding rather than the list itself. Either change the loop to loop over your listRoles and then databind after that or make your AdminRole.GetRolesList return the correct data (possibly by means of an overload if necessary).

Answer (score -2):

Do the databind after the foreach.-

Davide Piras also has a point but perhaps this is only an example of what you want to do.

Comment: What point would his foreach serve then if there is nothing in the collection to do work on?

Comment: Perhaps he didn't show the full code of what he want's to do.

Comment: No, the point is that if he is running any code on a collection via that foreach, if there are no items in there, then the code isn't doing anything.